# Parse multipart request apache camel rest DSL

Tags: java, apache, jakarta-ee, apache-camel

How to parse multipart request using camel rest DSL?

I am using camel java rest DSL with servlet component. Camel version is 2.19.3.

In camel version 2.15.2 multipart request parsing is working with following :

**web.xml**

```
<servlet>
      <servlet-name>CamelServlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.apache.camel.component.servlet.CamelHttpTransportServlet</servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   <!-- Camel servlet mapping -->
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>CamelServlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/api/rest/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   <filter>
      <filter-name>MultipartFilter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.MultiPartFilter</filter-class>
   </filter>
   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>MultipartFilter</filter-name>
      <servlet-name>CamelServlet</servlet-name>
   </filter-mapping>
```

**Rest DSL :**

```
rest("/file")
    .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.off)
    .consumes("multipart/form-data")
    .produces("application/json")
    .post("/upload")
        .route().process(caCertificateUploadProcessor);
```

**Processor:**

```
Message in = exchange.getIn();
System.out.println("Size:"+in.getAttachments().size());
```

For version 2.15.2 of camel I am getting attachment map size according to my multipart request. But when I update camel version 2.19.3 this is giving me attachment size zero always. It looks like the handling of the multipart request has been changed in some camel updates. I need to know how to get attachments in latest camel version.

Comment: provide more information in order to interact with more people.

Comment: @MananKalariya, I updated the question.

Comment: You should be able to still configure it via the web.xml, and then the rest-dsl should use it as-is.

Comment: @ClausIbsen, Can you please give me some example?

Comment: Are you still using the same web.xml? eg the only change you do with upgrade is to change the Camel version number, or do you do something more?

Comment: @ClausIbsen, I just upgraded the camel version and the same thing is not working anymore.

Comment: @JayTrivedi, did you find a solution to this?